# sidebar logo width

Tags: beamer, width, logos

I would like to place the institution logo at the bottom of the sidebar as wide as the whole sidebar.

I was wondering if there is a command that return the width of the sidebar, somthing similar to `\textwidth`.

Thanks in advance for your help

Update:
Yes, I am using beamer.
here is an example of my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\title{Title}
\author{My name}
\institute{My institute}
\date{\today}
\addtobeamertemplate{sidebar left}{}{
  \includegraphics[width = 0.15\textwidth]{logo}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Frame content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. I assume, that you use `beamer`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please specify at least which class are you using? Is it Beamer? I guess so, but a confirmation is definitely worth.

Comment: In many document styles (probably not `beamer`), the lengths `\PageLeftMargin+\hoffset` will give a distance from the left side of the paper to the text body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{sidebar left}{}{%
  \includegraphics[width=\beamer@sidebarwidth]{logo}%
}
\makeatother
```

Don't forget the `%` to prevent trailing spaces!

Comment: Thanks, I tried something like this before but without the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` commands and it was not compiling.

Comment: @Emanuele Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8353/1952 to understand why do you need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

Answer (score 1):

The sidebar width can be increased or decreased using

```
\usetheme[width=3cm]{{Berkeley}
```

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[width=3cm]{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\title{Title}
\author{My name}
\institute{My institute}
\date{\today}
\addtobeamertemplate{sidebar left}{}{
  \includegraphics[width = 0.33\textwidth]{albt}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Frame content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: beamersidebar]

However your first page will look ugly if you enlarge the sidebar

Comment: Thanks, but my purpose is not to modify the sidebar width but to get its with. In order to fit the logo size with the sidebar width.